# Want to create new data frames in R by subsetting a data frame in a loop and assign each data frame name based on i value

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame and I want to make new data frames for each month and assign the data frames the name of the month.

something like this:

```
monname <- as.character(month.abb)
for (i in monname) {
    i <- subset(dat,dat$Month==i)
    monname[i] <- i
}
```

I get an error messages

```
Error in monname[i] <- i : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Any ideas or alternative way of accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: Makes little sense, the error is in trying to assign a list to an atomic vector,  and you should NOT be reassigning index variables inside for-loops. Bad, bad, bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same split function as Mark, if it is important for you to save each of the resulting dataframes into your environment, you can use the "list2env" function.

```
df <- data.frame(
    month = rep(c("Jan","Mar","Apr"), 4)
    , somevalue = runif(12)
)
groups <- unique(df$month)


newdf_list <- split(df, f = df$month)
list2env(setNames(newdf_list, groups), .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in function for handling exactly this issue: `split`

You provide an indexable object (`data.frame` or vector) to split apart and a vector that provides the basis of splitting.  It returns a list of the resulting splits *named by the unique values of the splitting vector*.

Consider the following example.

```
dat = data.frame(Month = rep(month.name,2), 
                 MonAbb = rep(month.abb,2), 
                 value = runif(24),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat_abb = split(dat,dat$MonAbb)
dat_abb[["Aug"]]
#>     Month MonAbb     value
#> 8  August    Aug 0.9729210
#> 20 August    Aug 0.6742098
```